# How to access AJAX response variables in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can't access my variables through ajax using php.

**AJAX CODE**

```
$("input[name='absent[]'").change(function() {
    var obj = $(this);  //checkbox
    var valueZero = obj.val();
    var Code = obj.attr('data-Code');
    var value = obj.attr('data-session');
    /*var theTR = $(this).parent('tr').children().find('td:eq(0)').addClass('hidden');*/
    /*    alert( theTR.text());*/
    /*$(this).addClass('hidden');*/
    $.ajax({
        data: "{ code: '"+ Code +"', abt_prt: "+ valueZero +", InOut: "+ value +" }",  // need to access these variables in php
        type: "post",
        dataType:'json',
        url: "insertabsent.php",
        success: function(){
            obj.addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST))
{
   $code = $_POST['code']; //variable
   $absent_present = $_POST['abt_prt']; //variable
   $session = $_POST['InOut'];  //variable
   //need this variables to perform a insert query
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `print_r($_POST);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do try this :

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var mainString = "code="+Code+"&abt_prt="+valueZero+"&InOut="+value;
```

**IN AJAX**

```
data : mainString
```

**PHP**

```
$code = $_POST['code']; //variable
$absent_present = $_POST['abt_prt']; //variable
$session = $_POST['InOut'];  //variable
```

Answer (score 0):

use data like

```
data: { code:Code , abt_prt : valueZero , InOut : value },
```

and in php I don't really know what is $_REQUEST is but you can use

```
if(isset($_POST)){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing data variable to:

```
data: {"code":Code,"abt_prt":valueZero,"InOut":value},
```

Comment: the insert query is executing but the variables are still not accessible

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how AJAX parameters have to be sent. You do not need to send an index, you can send a simple Javascript object, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: { code: Code, abt_prt: valueZero, InOut:value},  // need to access these variables in php
    type: "post",
    dataType:'json',
    url: "insertabsent.php",
    success: function(){
        obj.addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

However, if for some reason you want to send a string like you did, then decode it using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: how can i decode it ? will it be done in the php file?

Comment: If you send the data as suggested initially in my code, then you do not need to decode it.